# RegEx parse XML file and return only url with file extension

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have the following xml file that is converted to string
I want to parse the xml file an return only the url with file extension

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<channel>
  <generator>GOA Celebrations</generator>
  <generator>GOA Celebrations</generator>
  <pubDate>13 Jan 2016</pubDate>
  <title>GOA Celebrations</title>
  <link>http://goframe.com.au/rss/herston-inbound</link>
  <language>en</language>
  <image>
    <url>http://goafame.com.au/site/templates/img/logo.png</url>
  </image>
  <item>
    <title>Herston Inbound - Wednesday, 13 Jan - Alex Peisker - 2015-12-21 09:26am - Live</title>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate>13 Jan 2016 10:32:01 AEST</pubDate>
    <link>http://goafame.com.au/gallery/entry/2991/</link>
    <enclosure url="http://goafame.com.au/site/assets/files/2991/final_cropped_shutterstock_114908098.jpg" length="" type="" />
    <guid isPermaLink="false">c5c1cb0bebd56ae38817b251ad72bedb</guid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Dog 1</title>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate>13 Jan 2016 10:32:01 AEST</pubDate>
    <link>http://goafame.com.au/gallery/entry/2991/</link>
    <enclosure url="http://animaliaz-life.com/data_images/dog/dog4.jpg" length="" type="" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Dog 2</title>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate>13 Jan 2016 10:32:01 AEST</pubDate>
    <link>http://goafame.com.au/gallery/entry/2991/</link>
    <enclosure url="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/12/21/6358631429926013411708851658_Dog-Pictures.jpg" length="" type="" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Dog 3</title>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate>13 Jan 2016 10:32:01 AEST</pubDate>
    <link>http://goafame.com.au/gallery/entry/2991/</link>
    <enclosure url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AkcfB3z0_-0/maxresdefault.jpg" length="" type="" />
  </item>
</channel>
```

My question is how to do this using

> Regular Exression

The desired output would be

> http://goafame.com.au/site/templates/img/logo.png
> http://goafame.com.au/site/assets/files/2991/final_cropped_shutterstock_114908098.jpg
> http://animaliaz-life.com/data_images/dog/dog4.jpg
> http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/12/21/6358631429926013411708851658_Dog-Pictures.jpg
>
> https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AkcfB3z0_-0/maxresdefault.jpg

Here's what I've try so far

```
Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                string rawString = doc.ToString();
                int posCounter = 0;
                foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
                {
                    posCounter++;
                    links.Add(new LinkModel
                    {
                        IsSelected = false,
                        XmlLink = m.Value,
                        NodePosition = posCounter
                    });
                }
```

**Note:**
XML file can come from any sources and some other url are not located in link element.Some are even nested. That's why I think of using RegEx rather than XDocument.

Comment: Why You needd regex? Using Xpath it will by one line of code : )

Comment: Don't use RegEx for this. Just use an XML parser. XDocument for example.

Comment: IMHO parsing XML using regular expressions are not a good idea. I'll go for DOM or SAX.

Comment: is it possible to get url using XDocumet (note that XML file are dynamic some of url's may not come from enclosure tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My pattern can match your sample. Tested here http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
https?://[^\s<"]+/[^\s<"]+(?:\.\w{3,4})
```

The idea is that finding all links that have a splash character (/) followed by a file name pattern (end with 3,4 characters extension).

Answer (score 2):

```
var allLinkValues = XDocument.Parse(doc.ToString())
                             .Root
                             .Elements("item")
                             .Select(itemElement => itemElement.Element("link").Value)
                             .ToList();
```

here

`XDocument.Parse(doc.ToString())` loads the document.
`Root` points to the root element
then we select all the "item" elements and select the value of the "link" element.

power of Linq2Xml!

XPath, XmlDocument are your other options.

in general if the string is well schemed, (XML, JSON, RDF etc.) do not opt for RegEx as the first option. There are well defined parsers for these type of documents.

And the above query should get you started on Xml navigation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but  my problem here is the xml is dynamic it may come from any rss feeds and some links are not located in link element